# Getting records which have closer date to given Input date

Tags: sql, pymssql

I have a table of data (the db is MSSQL): Input Date: 01-09-2014

```
ID  OrderNO PartCode FundId  Quantity lastmodified
417 2144     44917      A      100      31-08-2014
418 7235     11762      B        5      31-08-2014
419 9991     60657      C      100      31-08-2014
420 9992     60658      D       90      31-08-2014
421 9993     60659      A      100      31-07-2014
422 9994     60660      B       90      31-07-2014
421 9993     60659      C      100      31-07-2014
422 9994     60660      D       90      31-07-2014
```

I would like to make a query that returns set of records, but only for the lastmodified date which is closely lesser then the given Input date.

From the example table I would like to get back the following info:

```
ID  OrderNO PartCode FundId  Quantity lastmodified
417 2144     44917      A      100      31-08-2014
418 7235     11762      B        5      31-08-2014
419 9991     60657      C      100      31-08-2014
420 9992     60658      D       90      31-08-2014
```

Thanks!

Comment: Closely lesser means difference by how many days?

Comment: he means "closest" ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select ID,  OrderNO, PartCode, FundId, Quantity, lastmodified from Table where lastmodified = (select max(lastmodified) from Table where lastmodified < '01-09-2014')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from yourtable where lastmodified = (select max(lastmodified) from yourtable where lastmodified < inputdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you the result difference by two days from the given Input Date:
Note: Change the number 2 to any number as per your req.

```
 select * from table where lastmodified between DATEADD(day, -1, inputdate) AND DATEADD(day, -2, inputdate)
```

Comment: @GarethD : Question first line says db is MSSQL.

Comment: My bad, saw the MySQL tag which has now been removed.

Comment: @GarethD : Learnt MySQL Syntax for the above ans through you. I should thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the last update for each FundId before a certain date;

```
with cte as
(
    select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by FundId order by lastmodified desc) as rn 
  from @t where lastmodified < '2014-09-01'
)
select *
from cte  
where rn = 1;
```